# FCM : setting the TTL ("time_to_live" or lifespan) attribute with a Java Server (Google documentation is wrong/unclear)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've searched for hours and can't find an answer (lots of unanswered questions on SO, among other things).

---

### My current code

```
/**
 * Use when the server has determined how many Alerts are situated inside
 * a single Monitored Zone of a user.
 *
 * Documentation:
 * https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages
 *
 * @param registrationToken tokens of the devices the notif is sent to
 * @param mzName name of the Monitored Zone (can be its ID)
 * @param nbrAlertes number of alerts detected inside the MZ
 */
public static void sendMzLiveAlertNotif(ArrayList<String> registrationToken,
                                    String mzName, int nbrAlertes) {

    if(registrationToken.size() == 0 || nbrAlertes == 0 || mzName.isEmpty())
        return;

    registrationToken.forEach(token -> {
        // See documentation on defining a message payload.
        Message message = Message.builder()
                .putData("title", NotifType.NEW_LIVE_ALERT.getTitle())
                .putData("body", "\"" + mzName + "\" contient " + nbrAlertes + " alertes.")
                .putData("tag", mzName)
                .putData("nbrAlerts", nbrAlertes+"")
                .setToken(token)
                .build();

        try {
            // Send a message to the device.
            String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
            // Response is a message ID string.
            System.out.println("Successfully sent message: " + response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

This worked perfectly, until I wanted to add a lifespan to my notifications. I am still trying to figure out what is the proper way to do so with Java.

---

### My question

I'm wondering how I am supposed to impose a 30 hours lifespan to my message (and also why it works without me using the `setAndroidConfig` method that Google seems to use).

My server is coded in `Java`, and the notifications are pushed to an `Android` application.

My initial thought was to go for:

```
        Message message = Message.builder()
                .putData("title", NotifType.NEW_LIVE_ALERT.getTitle())
                .putData("body", "\"" + mzName + "\" contient " + nbrAlertes + " alertes.")
                .putData("tag", mzName)
                .putData("nbrAlerts", nbrAlertes+"")
                .setToken(token)
                .setAndroidConfig(AndroidConfig.builder()
                        .setTtl(3600 * 30) // 30 hours ?
                        .build())
                .build();
```

... but after seeing how Google uses the `AndroidConfig` for the whole thing, I'm wondering if I should too.

---

### Google Documentation

The only examples I can find are from Google themselves. Here is [an example](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/blob/master/src/test/java/com/google/firebase/messaging/MessageTest.java#L112):

```
  @Test
  public void testAndroidMessageWithoutNotification() throws IOException {
    Message message = Message.builder()
        .setAndroidConfig(AndroidConfig.builder()
            .setCollapseKey("test-key")
            .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
            .setTtl(10)
            .setRestrictedPackageName("test-pkg-name")
            .putData("k1", "v1")
            .putAllData(ImmutableMap.of("k2", "v2", "k3", "v3"))
            .build())
        .setTopic("test-topic")
        .build();
    Map<String, Object> data = ImmutableMap.<String, Object>of(
        "collapse_key", "test-key",
        "priority", "high",
        "ttl", "0.010000000s", // 10 ms = 10,000,000 ns
        "restricted_package_name", "test-pkg-name",
        "data", ImmutableMap.of("k1", "v1", "k2", "v2", "k3", "v3")
    );
    assertJsonEquals(ImmutableMap.of("topic", "test-topic", "android", data), message);
  }
```

Do you see the `.setTtl(10)`and the `"ttl", "0.010000000s", // 10 ms = 10,000,000 ns` parts? It confuses me. [Their documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) says (emphasis is mine):

> **time_to_live** : *Optional, number* : This parameter specifies how long (**in seconds**) the message should be kept in FCM storage if the
>   device is offline. The maximum time to live supported is 4 weeks, and
>   the default value is 4 weeks. For more information, see [Setting the
>   lifespan of a
>   message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl).

The link they tell us to read says:

> On Android and Web/JavaScript, you can specify the maximum lifespan of
>   a message. The value must be a duration from 0 to 2,419,200 seconds
>   (28 days), and it corresponds to the maximum period of time for which
>   FCM stores and attempts to deliver the message. Requests that don't
>   contain this field default to the maximum period of four weeks.

They clearly want the thing to be in **seconds**. Yet their tests show usage of **milliseconds** ?! It is frustrating to find so many examples in JavaScript, and almost nothing in Java within their documentation!

In itself, one can also find this **contradictory** [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/AndroidConfig.Builder.html#setTtl(long)):

> `public AndroidConfig.Builder setTtl (long ttl)`
>
> Sets the time-to-live duration of the message in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good case of confusing documentation.

You should go with `ms`, so for 30 hours you would get something like this:

```
        Message message = Message.builder()
                .putData("title", NotifType.NEW_USER_ALERT.getTitle())
                .putData("body", "\"" + mzName + "\" contient " + nbrAlertes + " alertes.")
                .putData("tag", mzName)
                .putData("nbrAlerts", nbrAlertes+"")
                .setToken(token)
                .setAndroidConfig(AndroidConfig.builder()
                        .setTtl(30*3600*1000) // 30 hours
                        .build())
                .build();
```